# Unable to Sync Tables in Django

Tags: django, database-connection

Currently programming in Python Django 1.4. In my files I have written CREATE TABLE functions for `productos` and `clientes` to be created in the MySQL database. When I checked with `python manage.py sqlall ventas` (`ventas` being the parent directory of `productos` and `clientes`), it outputs that snippet of code. However, when I tried to access them under localhost admin, I got the 
`1146, "Table 'demo.ventas_cliente' doesn't exist"` error. And these 2 tables do now show up in MySQL.

Initially I had dropped these 2 tables because there were some DB errors. I ran `syncdb` again but does not seem to retrieve those 2 tables. What seems to be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you don't type MySql commands directly, this may throw you many errors in the future. To create tables in Django you must create models. For example:

1) In ./Yourproject/apps/yourDBName create __ init __.py

2) in settings.py under "installed apps" add your new app. Example: yourproject.apps.yourapp

4) execute "python manage.py runserver"

5) create models.py into your new app

6) now you can create your models like that:

```
class myTable(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

7) if you want to access your new table from the admin, create admin.py in your app and type:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import myTable

admin.site.register(myTable)
#here, you can add more tables to the admin in the future
```

also, if you need to use foreign keys:

```
class parentTable(models.Model):
     idParent     = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     parentName   = models.CharField(null=False)

class childTable(models.Model):
     idChild          = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     MyParentName     = models.ForeignKey(parentTable, to_field='parentName')
     childName        = models.CharField(null=False)
```

**MORE INFO:** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/

Comment: Yes but they are in my models.py . But somehow `syncdb` is not linking them.